# What will be the total number of idempotent matrices of order $(n\times n) $ over $Z_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What will be the total number of idempotent matrices of order $(n\times n) $ over $Z_p$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the question, otherwise it just look like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: @jjag it's an interesting question, and unlikely to be homework. Let it stay.

Comment: The numbers for $p=2$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A132186 but no closed form formula is given there (which strongly suggests no closed form formula is known). I imagine the situation is similar for other $p$.

Comment: So, what do you think, A. Basunia?

Comment: I guess you've lost interest.